# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1, HOW TO RESOLVE THIS?

Tags: flutter, dart

Please see error bellow

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on SM G965F in debug mode...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
```

Compiler message:

```
    ../../../../minhpham/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
      ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^
    ../../../../minhpham/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
    ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
    Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
    build failed.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Script '/Users/minhpham/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 780

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
    > Process 'command '/Users/minhpham/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**AND SEE LOG BELLOW**

```
    2019-12-21 19:27:55.477 4569-5133/? D/bauth_FPBAuthService: thread id : 1, preenroll_flag : 0, nd cnt : 0, cso : 0, et : 0
    2019-12-21 19:27:55.477 4569-5133/? D/bauth_FPBAuthService: FPBAuthService, 9983
    2019-12-21 19:27:55.519 8312-8312/? I/SKBD: anc isTosAccept false
    2019-12-21 19:27:55.921 8312-8312/? I/chatty: uid=10160(com.sec.android.inputmethod) identical 2 lines
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.123 8312-8312/? I/SKBD: anc isTosAccept false
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.257 4337-10083/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getAudioPolicyConfig: audioParam;outDevice
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.258 4337-10083/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getNewOutputDevice() selected device 0
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.258 4337-10083/? V/APM_AudioPolicyManager: ### curdevice : 2
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.324 8312-8312/? I/SKBD: anc isTosAccept false
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.478 4569-5133/? D/bauth_FPBAuthService: pcf : 0x1012, 0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0, 
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.478 4569-5133/? D/bauth_FPBAuthService: thread id : 1, preenroll_flag : 0, nd cnt : 0, cso : 0, et : 0
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.478 4569-5133/? D/bauth_FPBAuthService: FPBAuthService, 9983
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.524 8312-8312/? I/SKBD: anc isTosAccept false
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.598 11472-11472/? I/omobile.apploc: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 18(32KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 55% free, 4MB/10MB, paused 670us total 139.080ms
    2019-12-21 19:27:56.725 8312-8312/? I/SKBD: anc isTosAccept false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to [cached_network_image 2.0.0-rc](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image/versions/2.0.0-rc)

**How to install?**
Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc
```

---

also, they have mentioned this issue in their pub.dev [Page](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

> If you are experiencing one of the following errors upgrade to 2.0.0-rc.

```
The method 'ScaledFileImage.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'
```

or

```
The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'
```

Comment: Check my updated answer. go to your `pubspec.yaml` and add `cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc`

Comment: Glad that helped:)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `cached_network_image: ^2.0.0-rc.1`

versions less than 1.3.1 have trouble after flutter 1.10.15 .

Don't forget to use flutter pub upgrade